# Does the range of all square root functions always equals to 0?

Tags: functions

I know that the domain of the square root function has to equal to the minimum possible number (0) to have all the other numbers equal to 0 or be more than 0, but since the x value has to make the value under the square root sign equal to 0, whenever we subtract the two values it always equals to 0, hence the range of the square root function is always = 0.

So, does the range of a square root function always equals to 0?

Comment: What does the reciprocal function have to do with square roots?

Comment: Never mind I meant the square root function sorry

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking.  The range of the square root function $f(x) = \sqrt{x}$ is $[0, \infty)$.

Comment: So it's always infinity, no matter what, right?

Comment: The function $f(x) = \sqrt{4 - x^2}$ has range $[0, 2]$ since its graph is the upper half of a semi-circle of radius $2$ centered at the origin.  The function $f(x) = 1 + \sqrt{1 - x^2}$ has range $[1, 2]$.  The range depends on what is inside the radical and what is outside the radical.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Thank you, I got it.

Answer (score 1):

Any value under a square root must be ≥ 0, not always equal to 0. Similarly, the min value of range is 0. Not all values of under root are equal to 0
Please do clear your basics.